# 'NSStringFromClass(Class _Nonnull __unsafe_unretained aClass)' method in iOS10 device will crash! --[CFString release]

Tags: ios10

My code is `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSStringFromClass([xxx class])]` to return cell, but it will crash in iOS10 device.

Comment: The Category code caused the crash

Answer (score 0):

usually you must specify a literal, AND set manually the same in Storyboard.

- Are you using all in code?
- are you using the name of class instead of it?

Comment: agree, bad programming practice to synthesise Identifer using class names.. anyway xxx is the class of?

Answer (score 0):

is wrong to use class name as ID, as in Storyboard You must set it.
if You write:

```
NSString * ID =  NSStringFromClass([CustomCell class]);
```

Yu got a string, but is NOT the ID.